# Speed adjustable MIDI playback

Tags: midi

I'm new to Ubuntu, and not well versed in technical issues.  As a musician, I practice along with MIDI files found online, such as on ABCnotation, and I need to slow them down at first.  Preferably they should be set to repeat in a loop, so I can practice as long as desired, without fumbling at controls.  Is there an app, or a way to set up for this?

Comment: Programs that allow editing MIDI files are called sequencers.